# how to prove an almost open set is lebesgue measurable?

Tags: real-analysis

If for every $\sigma > 0$, one can find an open set $U$ such that $m^*(U \Delta E)\le \sigma$, then how we prove $E$ is lebesgue measurable, which is for every $\sigma > 0$, one can contain $E$ in an open set F with $m^*(F \setminus E) \le \sigma$?

Comment: Is $m^*$ lebesgue measure?

Comment: Nope, $ m^* $ is outer measure.

Comment: This exercise is actually in Tao's book, which requires to show the equivalency of different criterion of lebesgue measurability....

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon>0$.

First we find an open $U$ such that $m^*(U\Delta E)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. The symmetric difference includes both $U\setminus E$ (which is helping us to cover $E$) and $E\setminus U$, the rascally portion of $E$ which $U$ fails to capture.  We'd like to rein in this bit.

By monotonicity, $m^*(E\setminus U) \le m^*(U\Delta E)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.  So, by outer regularity of Lebesgue outer measure, we can find an open set $V$ which contains $E\setminus U$ such that $m^*(V)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.  $V$ is just capturing all of the points that $U$ missed.

Let $F=U\cup V$.  Then $F$ is open, contains $E$, and $$m^*(F\setminus E)\le m^*(V\setminus E) + m^*(U \setminus E) \le m^*(V)+m^*(U \setminus E) < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon.$$

Comment: Thanks very much, @Josh! However, i am still not clear about "by definition of outer measure, we can find an open set V which contains $ E \setminus U $ such that $ m^*(V\setminus(E\setminus U))<\frac{\epsilon}{2} $ ". It seems to me that it's the definition of lebesgue measure instead of outer measure...

Comment: I think what is valid is $ m*(V)-m*(E \setminus U) < \frac{\epsilon}{2} $, not $ m^*(V\setminus(E\setminus U))<\frac{\epsilon}{2} $ as you suggested....

Comment: Aaaah!  You're right.  And that won't be enough.  I'll try to rework my answer.

Comment: Everything should be fine now.  I stopped trying to make $V\setminus(E\setminus U)$ small and just settled for a small $V$, which we get from outer regularity.